# how can I change in memory db to file db In JAVA?

Tags: sqlite, spring-jdbc, in-memory-database

The sqlite configuration in spring boot is

sqlite.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite::memory:

I confirmed that the data was inserted, but I want to get this sqlite as a real file.

Do you know what to do?

Comment: I found a solution. You can use the backup query provided by sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.properties setting

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:file:memorydb.db?mode=memory&cache=shared
```

test code

```
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:file:memorydb.db?mode=memory&cache=shared");
 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

 File tmpFile = File.createTempFile(name, ".db");

 stmt.executeUpdate("backup to " + tmpFile.getAbsolutePath());


 tmpFile.deleteOnExit();
 stmt.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd want to do that because normally one would say that they want to move from using an in-memory database to an actual persistence database. So if I'm getting you correctly, you want to know how to write data to a file please refer to this article https://www.journaldev.com/878/java-write-to-file. So being able to write to a file is not an alternative but a database and doing this can co-exist.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: While this link might provide some limited, immediate help, an answer [should include sufficient context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, to make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. In addition, other users tend to respond negatively to answers which are [barely more than a link to an external site](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370), and they [might be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).